# Using a loaded image in a webgl texture

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to upload a texture to webgl, and most tutorials do something like this:

```
var textureImage = new Image();
textureImage.src = "img/texture.png";
textureImage.onload = function() { ...texture loading code... };
```

So the texture doesn't actually get uploaded to webgl until later, after the image has loaded.

However, I have an image on the DOM that I want to use as a texture, and this image will for sure be loaded because my JavaScript doesn't run until all of the page's content has fully loaded.

How do I get that image on the DOM and upload it to webgl immediately? Instead of waiting for a callback.

Comment: Just dont put the texture loading code in a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not because your page has fully loaded that your images are loaded too. They are not necessary on your page.

Even if that is the case, you can use `onload` callback without problem: it will be called as soon as you start the image loading if it is already loaded.

If your try to bind a texture that is not fully loaded, your surface will use instead a complete white texture (or black, in some cases). So you should see the difference yourself.

By the way: to prevent a load before your callback set, it is preferable to set your callback function *before* your source:

```
var textureImage = new Image();
textureImage.onload = function() { ...texture loading code... }; // First the callback...
textureImage.src = "img/texture.png"; // Then the source.
```